# Looking for single tooltip per graph in xy chart amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Im looking for function of amcharts4 for shown single tooltip in multi xy chart by mouse over

Comment: We need more information to help you. Would you be able to provide a sample of your multi charts, e.g. on CodePen? What is it the user should be mousing over that a single tooltip should display on? With or without Chart XYCursor? What should display in the tooltip?